# Magento2 : Auto Select Options for Products with Multiple Options

Tags: magento2, attributes, option

I'm trying to get url with already selected options.

If I have only one options, code is working fine adding #{attribute_id}={attribute_value} after url.

https://nyhomedecor.com/cordless-dual-sided-led-lighted-vanity-mirror-1x-5x-or-1x-10x.html#159=28

This code is not working when I have more than one option.

https://nyhomedecor.com/surround-lighttm-wall-mount-mirror-5x-or-7x.html#155=21&163=115&159=32

Any idea how can I make this work?

Comment: Curious to see... might need a javascript solution for this.

Comment: have you get any solution for this issue?

Answer (score -1):

You can try the code like this.

```
https://nyhomedecor.com/surround-lighttm-wall-mount-mirror-5x-or-7x.html?155=21&163=115&159=32
```

In your URL, need to replace `#` with `?`.

Comment: is that working for you, when you access this url the options are selected? for me it's not.

Comment: If you are talking about the auto select in drodown that show on that page, then you need to some code to make it working, because that is custom option of product.

Comment: It's not custom option. There are options based on attributes. If you check the first url, you'll see it's working when I have only one option. But it's not working when I have two or more.

Comment: you need to do custom code to auto select from URL value when attribute is render.